# Play two videos simultaneously with sync in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I am busy with a project where two videos have to play on top of each other. 
Like the one in the following site, http://kindnessday.sg/home#/kindness/home
Because of the large filesize I cannot embed the videos in the swf. It will become too large. Therefore the video's must be loaded thro' webstream link. But First video plays before the second video and causing the videos unsynced.

Is there a way to play both video at the same time?

```
var stream = 'http://mydomain/clip1.mp4'
var stream1 = 'https://mydomain/clip2.mp4'

var http_stream:URLStream = null
var http_stream1:URLStream = null

var video:Video = new Video() // the video is used only to ensure that stream is playing 
var video1:Video = new Video() // the video is used only to ensure that stream is playing

addChild(video1)
addChild(video)

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection()
    nc.connect(null)
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc)
    ns.client = new Object()
    ns.client.onMetaData = function(e){}
    ns.play(null)

var ns1:NetStream = new NetStream(nc)
    ns1.client = new Object()
    ns1.client.onMetaData = function(e){}
    ns1.play(null)

video.attachNetStream(ns)
video1.attachNetStream(ns1)

http_stream = new URLStream();
http_stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, on_Progress)
http_stream.load(new URLRequest(stream))

http_stream1 = new URLStream();
//http_stream1.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, on_Progress1)
http_stream1.load(new URLRequest(stream1))

function on_Progress(e:ProgressEvent):void {

    var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray()
    http_stream.readBytes(b, 0, http_stream.bytesAvailable)
    ns.appendBytes(b)

    var b1:ByteArray = new ByteArray()
    http_stream1.readBytes(b1, 0, http_stream1.bytesAvailable)
    ns1.appendBytes(b1)

    if (ns.appendBytes(b)==ns1.appendBytes(b1)){
        ns.play(stream);
        ns1.play(stream1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not not check **[how much of each video has loaded](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#bytesLoaded)** and when you have enough amount (you decide) then you can run some function to play both netstreams...

```
var min_amount : int = 500000; //for 500 kb minimum
var check_if_ready : Boolean = true;
```

Also on progressEvent function of loading (URLloader or URLstream???)..

```
if ( check_if_ready == true )
{
    if( myA_NetStream.bytesLoaded >= min_amount && myB_NetStream.bytesLoaded >= min_amount ) 
    { 
        myA_NetStream.play(); myB_NetStream.play();  

        //reset since not needed on further progressEvents during this load
        check_if_ready = false;
    }
}
}
```

This should only play when both videos have loaded x-amount of bytes. Therefore you can be sure none starts before another)

For better synchronization control you should get into handling bytes in Flash/AS3 and using the `AppendBytes` method because then you can control playback on a frame-by-frame basis for both NetStreams.

Comment: The `appendBytes` in your code isnt doing anything. It never works with MP4 directly (you must re-package that data like in FLV container file). Anyways this can be achieved without `appendBytes` but its better if you know it. I will update later when I get to fix your current code...